# Formatting an image to take up max size of 1 page when printing

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

I'm working on an html page that shows a chat conversation, and I'd like it to be able to be printer friendly so that it can easily be exported to PDF.  My problem is that long images can span multiple pages.  I'd like these to take up a max height of 1 page, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Here's how it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWMcO.png

Here's the code I'm working with:
https://jsfiddle.net/BigJeng/7k1ty7fj/

Messages are set to take up no more than 60% width.

```css
/* message containers */

.message {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: table;
}


/* sent message container */

.sent {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* message wrapper to limit width */

.message-wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}


/* Style time text */

.time {
  color: #999;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-wrapper right">
  <span class="time right">3/18/18 4:22 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent right">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rzM7V7J.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />
```

How can I make the image/date div be a max height of 1 8.5" x 11" piece of paper @ 600 dpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your issue:

```
@media print {
    img {page-break-inside: avoid;max-height: 95vh;max-width: 100%;width: auto;}
}
```

Just add the above CSS to your code.

The `page-break-inside: avoid;max-height: 95vh` will make the image fit inside the print page and `@media print` will make sure that it's only used while printing.

Working fiddle with your own code.

```css
/* message containers */

.message {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: table;
}


/* sent message container */

.sent {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* message wrapper to limit width */

.message-wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto
}

.right {
  float: right;
}


/* Style time text */

.time {
  color: #999;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media print {
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    max-height: 95vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Paul "Wrecking" Crewe</h1>
<h3>555-555-5555</h3>
<br>

<div class="message-wrapper right">
  <span class="time right">5/8/17 12:23 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent right">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper ">
  <span class="time">5/8/17 12:23 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message">Haha yeah</div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper right">
  <span class="time right">5/8/17 12:23 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent right">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper ">
  <span class="time">5/8/17 12:23 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper right">
  <span class="time right">12/6/17 3:56 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent right">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ImlYX.gif">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper right">
  <span class="time right">3/18/18 4:21 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent right">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ldSywk2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper">
  <span class="time">3/18/18 4:21 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WIaOSv6.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper">
  <span class="time">3/18/18 4:21 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pNdgqYe.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />

<div class="message-wrapper right">
  <span class="time right">3/18/18 4:22 PM</span>
  <br>
  <div class="message sent right">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rzM7V7J.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" />
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media` rule in css to apply specific styling when the media is print.

```
<style tyle="text/css">
   @media print
   {
      .message{
         //print specific styles go here for div with class as message
      }
   }
</style>
```